# Performance and temperature both massively increase while plugged in on my lenovo ideapad gaming laptop but stay extremely low while on battery

Tags: laptop, battery, gaming, charging

Laptop specs: Processor; Intel core i5-10300H 2.50 GHz , 8 gigs ram ideapad gaming laptop lenovo 81Y4 (less than a month old with all drivers updated) Nvidia geforce 1650 and intel uhd graphics which isnt used

Overview: Whilst plugged in, the laptops potential performance, temperature and fans drastically increase, i'm talking from 40-50 fps to 300-400 fps whilst playing low end games such as minecraft and temperatures of up to 70 degrees (and on high end games even apparently 100 degrees!) and obviously the fan roars during such occurrences. The temperature does calm down to around 45-60 with settings lowered but the temperature stays pretty high even when lowered to 30 fps. The major problem with this is that gaming often takes alot of battery power over long terms and it is both distracting and worrying to have the fans roaring at max speed while playing modded minecraft (not very graphically intensive whatsoever) only while plugged in and having to unplug the charger to allow my laptop to cool down. Lastly i've noticed that while on desktop, even though charging only increases the 44c to 47-49 the fan noise increases from inaudible to very noticable.

What i've tried: To be clear, any research or changes done to my laptops settings have been both minimal and after i have dealt with this problem for a couple of weeks. I was unable to find any performance related tweaks on the basic windows settings and the nvidia cap of 30 fps on battery was still only reaching 40-50 fps when capped at 60 proving that charging was definitely performing much better for some reason.

Sorry if i am a bit unclear in some areas, this is my first time making a post like this; feel free to ask about any areas i have been unclear on, hopefully i can get some insight on how to solve my strange problem.

Comment: Does this persist after the battery is fully charged? Charging is not a 100% efficient process and will heat up you battery and device until it is fully charged.

Comment: In my experience, the laptop is always having the problem while charging during gaming, whether fully charged or not, probably because battery is still being drained enough for the charger to use a significant amount of voltage. Also other testing that ive done shows that some games are unplayable unless the laptop is plugged in, with the fps quadrupling the second i plug in the charger.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > System > Power and Sleep > Additional Power Settings >

From there you can find 'Create a power plan' or 'Change Plan Settings'.  Both will allow you to set things up plugged in or on battery as you like.